# How can I use number as key?

Tags: javascript

I have ids like as numbers 374,242,435

I want to use this as key of hash for the object.

```
var json = [];
ids = [374,242,435];
for(let i in ids) {
    var id = ids[i];
    json[id] = []; // it makes 372 array!!! 
    json[id]['name'] = name;
    json[id]['color'] = color;
}
```

Can I make object using number as key????

---

This is my silly mistake

I just changed `var json = [];` -> `var json = {};` it works.

and thank you for your comments.

Comment: `var json = {};`...?

Comment: This comment just above. However, bear in mind that the browser will silently convert your numbers to strings, so actually they will be strings, not numbers.

Comment: Also you may want to consider not mixing `let/const` and `var` :)

Comment: AH,, I changed [] to {} . it works... That was my silly mistake

Answer (score 2):

```
let json = {};
let ids = [374,242,435];
for(let i in ids) {
    let id = ids[i];
    json[id] = {
        name: 'some name',
        color: '#ff0000'
    };
}
```

EDIT: A better version

```
let json = {};
let ids = [374,242,435];
ids.forEach((id) => {
    json[id] = {
        name: 'some name',
        color: '#ff0000'
    };
});
```

Comment: It's not recommended to use `in` to loop over an array like this. `of` is the preferred method. `ids` should have `const`, otherwise it's a global. Also, it's a good idea to add some text description of what this is. Code-only answers are generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map to store key-value pair. In Map, key will not just be string.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = {};

var ids = [374,242,435];

for(const i of ids) {
    json[i] : {
     name : 'name',
     color : '#colorcode'
    }
}
```